# How to calculate the PSD from the complex calculated STFT?

Tags: power-spectral-density, spectrogram, stft, scipy

I have calculated the STFT with scipy python library:

```
f_spec, t_spec, Spectro= sc.signal.spectrogram(My_Signal, fs=1.0, window='hamming', nperseg=180,
                        noverlap=None, nfft=2048, detrend=False, return_onesided=False, scaling='density',
                        axis=-1, mode='complex')
```

I wanted to get the same result as spectrogram function of MATLAB and now I want to calcluate its PSD in dB.
In fact I have found several expression in internet such as :

```
PSD=Spectro^2
```

or :

```
PSD = 10*log10(abs(Spectro))
```

I am not sure what to use can any one help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if you have complex spectrum and need PSD in dB the mathematical equation is

$$P_{xx} = 20\cdot\log_{10}|X_{x}|,$$ 
where $P_{xx}$ is your PSD in dB and $X_{x}$ is your complex STFT spectrum (variable `Spectro` in your case).

In SciPy documentation for [scipy.signal.spectrogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html) is mentioned, that you can compute spectrogram with different modes (‘psd’, ‘complex’, ‘magnitude’, ‘angle’, ‘phase’). You have chosen `mode='complex'`, which returns complex STFT, so you should get PSD from equation above. If you have chosen `mode='psd'` you would get PSD e.g. $S_{xx}$ (`Spectro` in your case) in the first place and to convert it to dB your equation is $$P_{xx} = 10\cdot\log_{10}S_{xx}.$$

However, if you want to plot same spectrogram as the MATLAB one I would choose equivalent [matplotlib.pyplot.specgram](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.specgram.html), which is very similar and you can plot PSD already in dB with this tool.

Answer (score 3):

I normally use the Welch method to calculate and plot the PSD of a signal.

```
signal_f, signal_psd = sp.welch(signal, sampling_frequency, return_onesided=False, nperseg=256)
signal_f = np.fft.fftshift(signal_f)
signal_psd = np.fft.fftshift(signal_psd)

plt.semilogy(signal_f, signal_psd, label = 'PSD')
```

Maybe it helps you!

Comment: can I use the welch method without overlapping because I aim to calculate the PSD in dB without overlapping

Comment: Yes, although I always used it on default settings. I just tried with noverlap = 0. Refer here, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html. The results are slightly different but not much.